# Conditional Probabilty of picking no black ball with red mark

Tags: probability

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE QUESTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Ftj.jpg)
Conditional probabilty question please help me with this question

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** There are three possible cases that satisfy the antecedent—that at least one black ball is picked: BW, WB, and BB.  (It is important to consider BW and WB distinct, or else you will undercount the cases.)  Since the selections are done with replacement, the probability of BW is

$$
P(\text{BW}) = P(\text{B}) \times P(\text{W}) = \frac14 \times \frac34 = \frac{3}{16}
$$

The joint probability that the sequence of selections is BW, *and* there is no red dot in the two selections, is

$$
P(\text{BW, no red dot}) = P(\text{B, no red dot}) \times P(\text{W, no red dot})
                         = \frac14 \times \frac45 \times \frac34 = \frac{3}{20}
$$

Repeat this process for the sequences WB and BB, keeping in mind that for the sequence BB, both draws of a black ball have to avoid a red dot.  Then your desired probability is

\begin{align}
P(\text{no red dot} & \mid \text{at least one black ball}) \\
    & = \frac{P(\text{no red dot and (BW or WB or BB)}}{P(\text{BW or WB or BB})} \\
    & = \frac{P(\text{BW, no red dot}) + P(\text{WB, no red dot}) + P(\text{BB, no red dot})}{P(\text{BW}) + P(\text{WB}) + P(\text{BB})}
\end{align}

Comment: Whats the final answer coming?? mine is coming 0.78 according to ur solution.. or if possible please complete the solution

Comment: So you need someone to do the arithmetic for you ?

Comment: @cocgame1: The other answer (as of now) has the final answer.  Looks like you have it right.

Answer (score 1):

The probability **(of picking at least one black ball)** is **1**-probability **(that no black balls are picked)**.

That's $1 - \displaystyle \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2=\frac{7}{16}$.

Call this P(Black).

The probability **(of picking no black balls with a red dot AND that at least one black ball is picked)** is the same as the probability of **(picking no black balls with a red dot minus the probability that two white balls are chosen)**.

And that is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{95}{100}\right)^2-\frac{9}{16}=\frac{361}{400}-\frac{225}{400}=\frac{136}{400}=\frac{17}{50}$.

Call this P(B&R).

The conditional probability of P(R|B), that is R given that B happened, is $\displaystyle \frac{P(B\&R)}{P(B)}=\frac{17}{50}*\frac{16}{7}=\boxed{0.78}$

---

So in short.

P(Black) = At least one black ball chosen

P(Red) = No reds chosen

P(Red|Black) = P(Red&Black)/P(Black)